# Use node Path module with angular 6

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, path

I'm trying to use the module Path in an Angular 6 project.

I found this post to fix the issue :

https://gist.github.com/niespodd/1fa82da6f8c901d1c33d2fcbb762947d

it says to add a script :

```
const fs = require('fs');
const f = 'node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/browser.js';

fs.readFile(f, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  var result = data.replace(/node: false/g, 'node: {crypto: true, stream: true}');

  fs.writeFile(f, result, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
  });
});
```

And declare it in package.json :

```
{...
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node patch.js",
    ...
  }
}
```

But when I'm trying to use it in a service, just import it like this :

```
import {join} from 'path';
```

It says that the module Path cannot be found.

---

How can I correct this ?

Comment: Are you trying to import a node module into Angular? Angular is front end and Node is back end. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: see also https://blog.lysender.com/2018/07/angular-6-cannot-resolve-crypto-fs-net-path-stream-when-building-angular/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting problem.

I managed to get Path module work on my Angular project.

Here are the steps.I use node 8, angular 6.

1: install path.

```
  npm install path
```

This is an exact copy of the NodeJS ’path’ module published to the NPM registry.

2, I also installed @types/node as in Angular we are using typescript.
Although later I removed this module and path module seems still works.

3, run the above script using

```
node patch.js
```

I manually run it and go to  'node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/browser.js' to check the file actually changed.

4, I put

```
  import {join} from 'path';
```

in one of my component.ts file

```
 let x = join('Users', 'Refsnes', '..', 'demo_path.js');
    console.log("-------------------------------------------------");
    console.log(x);
```

in a Component's onInit() function.

and run `"ng serve"` 
 I saw the expected output in my console when loading the webpage.

```
-------------------------------------------------
Users/demo_path.js
```

So this method does work. I am not sure which step you did wrong. My guess would be the first step as I tried if not do step 3 there's different error message. Please check your node_modules folder and verify path folder exists and reinstall it if necessary.

Comment: Maybe running it with `node patch.js` did the trick. It just started working as expected out of nowhere

Answer (score -1):

1. Be sure to have node types installed: `npm install --save-dev @types/node`
2. Import path: `import * as path from 'path';`

Comment: Path is installed, when I try to use Join for example the IDE is capable of auto completing the import but still tells me that path's module is not found

Comment: Does not work in the browser because the browser has no path module.